# Method OnCreate being called again when I return from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Imagine the app has 2 activities, A and B. From A, you push a button that starts B.
From B, you push another button that runs `setResult(RESULT_CANCEL, new Intent()); finish();`
This way, the view pops back to A.

I'm testing this on two devices, one running Gingerbread (GB), the other running Jellybean (JB).

On GB, when I return form B to A, the method the method `onCreate` is not called, which I believe means the activity has not been deallocated (`onDestroy` was not called either).

However on JB, the method `onCreate` **is** called again, and I don't understand why.

The big issue is that in my app, the `onCreate` is used to load data from the internet. This way, JB will always reload that data, even when it's been downloaded already.

What exactly is happening here, why do they behave differently?

Comment: Are you using `startActivityForResult()` to go from A to B? And what `Intent` are you using to go back to A?

Comment: Different garbage collecting? Your activity may get cleared out in JB because it is more rigorous about what it keeps loaded in the background. Have you tried saving it's state and then restoring it via it's Bundle in onCreate?

Comment: @codeMagic Yes, I am. To go back, I use a new, "empty" `Intent`.

Comment: When you use the "empty" `Intent`, wouldn't THAT cause the activity to call `onCreate`?

Comment: @Adam, apparently, it doesn't on Gingerbread.

Comment: @Adam No, that is what you should use when returning this way. That is how `onActivityResult()` gets called. Otherwise, it *should* and *would* call `onCreate()`. Which is why I asked because I see a lot of people use a populated constructor and wonder why `onCreate()` is called.

Comment: As @zgc7009 stated, JB is more rigorous with it's gcing. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle shoes some information about when each of the lifecycle methods are called, and in `onDestroy`, it can be called if the system needs memory previously allocated to activities in a paused/stopped state. JB is [probably] destroying your activity because it wants the memory back, and is therefore calling `onCreate` when you return.

Comment: Just read the Android 4.1 API version information. Seems as though they restructured their backstack navigation. Not sure if it exactly what is causing the difference in cleanup between the API's, but it very well could be https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The framework will call `onCreate()` when it needs to create a new instance of your Activity, which is likely what is happening here.

It is perfectly acceptable for the framework to destroy your Activity after you've navigated away from it (`onStop()`), and re-create it when you come back. There are no guarantees about when this will happen.

*Ordinarily*, this doesn't happen until there is memory pressure, but this varies from device to device (and of course depends on the operating load).  You can force this behavior to happen immediately by enabling "Don't Keep Activities" in `Settings -> Developer Options`.

Finally, you can also use this command to look at the activity hierarchy directly: `adb shell dumpsys activity activities`.  It takes some experience to decode everything, but should give you a rough idea of the Activity Manager's view of the world at any point in time.

Comment: Only downside to this is that your general user isn't going to want to play with their settings to get their app to work appropriately, especially messing with Developer Options.

Comment: @zgc7009 He's saying that as a developer, you can enable this setting to test that your app works properly under these conditions.

Comment: @kcoppock yea had to read more into the actual options. I thought it was doing something different. Good for debugging.

Comment: @zgc7009 True - the main reason it's hidden behind a special "unlock" sequence in recent releases of Android.

Comment: That explains. I have an iOS background, where we sort of don't need to worry about the "Activity Stack" (not that much). This along with @zgc7009 comment about saving and restoring states answer my question (although I'm yet to learn how to solve my problem).

Comment: @mik3y another quick question: even though the activity is destroyed, the system will keep track the it is in the stack, right? And it will know it needs to save the state to be reloaded later. If then I pop this activity (go back to an even earlier activity than "A", for instance), is it correct to think that the system will clear it for good, and if I ever start another "A" activity it will be loaded from scratch, without trying to reload the state?

Comment: @Guilherme Yes, if you pop past the activity -- or call finish() -- the system will infer that you're done with that particular instance and destroy it.

Comment: @Guilherme It takes some experience to decode, but, for the best source of truth as to "what's on the back stack", you can use this (somehwat obscure) command: `adb shell dumpsys activity activities`.  This gives you the hierarchy of stacks directly from the Activity Manager.  Different "tasks", or apps, have their own back histories -- just like multiple tabs in a desktop web browser.